# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'border'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

This error has been driving me crazy ! Anyway, I have created a simple jQuery plugin that I called "border", but I get this error :

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'border'**

For the record, jQuery is included only **once**, and it's included before my plugin.

I have used this to avoid conflicts :

```
<pre>
var $jq = $.noConflict();
//$.noConflict();
$jq("li").borderX('1px solid blue');
</pre>
```

**EDIT :**

This is my plugin's code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.fn.borderX = function (params) {
        params = $.extend({width: 'null', color: 'null', radius: 'null'}, params);
        this.each(function () {
            var $t = $(this);
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(params);
            if (typeof response == 'object') { //It is JSON
                if (params.width) {
                    $t.css('border-width:', params.width);
                }
                if (params.color) {
                    $t.css('border-color:', params.color);
                }
                if (params.radius) {
                    $t.css('border-radius:', params.radius);
                }
            } else {
                $t.css('border', params);
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
});
```

The HTML code from which I call the plugin named "borderX" is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.borderX.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq = $.noConflict();
//$.noConflict();
$jq("li").borderX('1px solid blue');
</script>
```

**EDIT °2 :**

```
$.fn.border = function (options) {
    var params = $.extend({width: 'null', color: 'null', radius: 'null'}, options);
    this.each(function () {
        var $t = $(this);
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(params);
        if (typeof response == 'object') { //It is JSON
            if (params.color) {
                $t.css('border-color:', params.color);
            }
            if (params.radius) {
                $t.css('border-radius:', params.radius);
            }
        } else {
            $t.css('border', params);
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: And how do you setup your plugin?

Comment: Please post your plugin, _called "border"_, you are calling `borderX` method.

Comment: I have actually changed the name to "borderX" and I get the same error.
I've been calling "borderX".

Comment: The error is not in the code above - it's in your plugin.  Can we see the code for that?

Comment: You didn't provide an ounce of code from your plugin. Two things pop to mind - you're not loading the plugin or you're not exposing your plugin to jQuery, therefore the method won't exist if jQuery doesn't "see" it.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my post so you can check the plugin code =)
Hopefully, I'll resolve this^^

Comment: You're calling `borderX` as soon as it reaches it in the code, but the plugin is only defined at `document.ready`.  If you change the plugin to run immediately it will resolve this issue

Comment: The problem is that you put you plugin code into `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { })`. So the plugin is initialized after DOM is loaded but by that moment you already called `noConflict`.

Comment: Oh I see, but how can I reslove this ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 1st and last lines of your plugin so it's not wrapped in `document.ready`

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.borderX = function(params) {
        params = $.extend( {width: 'null', color: 'null', radius: 'null'}, params);
        this.each(function() {
            var $t = $(this);
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(params);

            if(typeof response == 'object')
            { //It is JSON
                if(params.width){$t.css('border-width',params.width);}
                if(params.color){$t.css('border-color',params.color);}
                if(params.radius){$t.css('border-radius',params.radius);} 
            }
            else
            {
                $t.css('border',params);
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I did, but actually, I get another error. It seems that 'extend' isn't recognized :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

Comment: Alright, now I used this :

    $jq("li").border({width: '2px', color: 'red', radius: '1px'});

It generates the same error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

Comment: There must be something conflicting elsewhere because I can copy and paste that code into the console on this page and run it without errors and add borders to everything (there was a typo in the above code that I fixed - I removed the `:` from after each style attribute.)

Comment: That's very weird :( I still get this :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined jquery.border.js:3
$.fn.border jquery.border.js:3
(anonymous function) events.html:19
(anonymous function)

Comment: It's exactly my jquery.border.js file !

Comment: Here's the error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined jquery.border.js:2
$.fn.border jquery.border.js:2
(anonymous function)

Comment: I've made another amendment.  Try that now.  I've wrapped the whole plugin in an anonymous function that passes jQuery in as a parameter.

Comment: Now, it says :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o ( jquery.min.js:3 )

This time, I guess the error is jQuery's ? o_O I just don't get it.

Comment: Is this publicly hosted?  I'll happily have a look at it if I can

Comment: No, it's not hosted unfortunately :/